# In R: shorten list from behind till a certain value

Tags: r

Suppose i have many and larger lists than in this example.

```
ID <- c(2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,9,9,9,9)
Rounds <- c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
solution <- c(as.character('[[-1,1,1,-1],[1,-1,1,-1]]'),as.character('[[-1,1,-1,-1],[1,-1,1,-1]]'),as.character('[[-1,1,1,-1],[1,-1,-1,-1]]') )
solution_resp <- c(as.character('[[-1,1,1,1],[1,1,-1,1]]'),as.character('[[1,-1,1,-1],[1,-1,1,1]]'),as.character('[[-1,1,1,1],[1,-1,1,-1]]'))

dt <- data.frame(ID,Rounds,solution,solution_resp)

dt$solution <- gsub('],[',',', dt$solution, fixed=TRUE)
dt$solution <- gsub('[[',''  , dt$solution, fixed=TRUE)
dt$solution <- gsub(']]',''  , dt$solution, fixed=TRUE)

dt$solution <- as.list(strsplit(dt$solution, ","))

dt$solution_resp <- gsub('],[',',', dt$solution_resp, fixed=TRUE)
dt$solution_resp <- gsub('[[',''  , dt$solution_resp, fixed=TRUE)
dt$solution_resp <- gsub(']]',''  , dt$solution_resp, fixed=TRUE)

dt$solution_resp <- as.list(strsplit(dt$solution_resp, ","))
```

Looks like this:

```
   ID Rounds                    solution             solution_resp
1   2      0  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1  -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1
2   2      1 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1
3   2      2 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
4   2      3  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1  -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1
5   5      0 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1
6   5      1 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
7   5      2  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1  -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1
8   5      3 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1
9   9      0 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
10  9      1  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1  -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1
11  9      2 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1
12  9      3 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
```

In the lists dt$solution_resp I would like to drop all 1 from behind until the first -1 appears (counting from right to left).

In the example this would mean shortening the lists by taking off the last element in first row (and every third row). In the second row (and every third) the list shall be shorted by two elements. The third row remains as it is because there is a -1 at the last position already.

Then, I want the dt$solution lists to have the same length.

Solution:

```
   ID Rounds                    solution             solution_resp
1   2      0  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
2   2      1 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1         1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
3   2      2 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
4   2      3  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
5   5      0 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1         1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
6   5      1 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
7   5      2  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
8   5      3 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1,        1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
9   9      0 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
10  9      1  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1,    -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
11  9      2 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1,        1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
12  9      3 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
```

Comment: I'm confused, is `solution_resp` the input, and `solution` the desired output?

Comment: Yes, although not really important for the question. I want to compare them afterwards, but only until the last response has been given as indicated by the last -1 in solution_resp.  So I want to cut both lists.

Comment: I mean, it's very important for answering the question to understand what is the input and what is the desired result. To help you we need to understand what to start with and what the goal is. That's not clear here.

Comment: I've made the example a litte more complicated and added a desired solution. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `Position` of the last `-1` starting at the `right=` and only keep up until this point:

```
lapply(dt$solution_resp, \(x) head(x, Position(identity, x=="-1", right=TRUE)) )
```

In the circumstance where there could be rows without a `-1` at all:

```
lapply(dt$solution_resp, \(x) 
  head(x, pmin(Position(identity, x=="-1", right=TRUE), Inf, na.rm=TRUE)))

#[[1]]
#[1] "-1" "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "-1"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "1"  "-1" "1"  "-1" "1"  "-1"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "-1" "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "-1" "1"  "-1"
#...
```

Comment: I tried it with this solution because it is so beautifully short. 
With my real data I get the error that there are lists without -1. Could this be dealt by just filling NA instead of a list? Or anything else that does not contain 1?   Fehler in checkHT(n, dx <- dim(x)) : 
  invalid 'n' -  must contain at least one non-missing element, got none

Comment: @SDahm - see if the edit helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tad longer than @thelatemail's one-liner.

```r
dt |> 
  dplyr::select(
    ID,
    Rounds,
    s            = solution_resp,
  ) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    s = gsub("\\[|\\]", "", s),               # Remove the brackets
  ) |> 
  tibble::rowid_to_column("row_id") |> 
  tidyr::separate_rows(s, sep = ",") |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    s = dplyr::recode(s, "-1" = T, "1" = F)   # Make the math easier later
  ) |> 
  dplyr::group_by(row_id, ID, Rounds) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    index       = seq_len(dplyr::n()),        # Remember the ordering
  ) |> 
  dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(index)) |>       # Reverse
  dplyr::mutate(
    cumulative = dplyr::cumany(s),            # Find the first (last) 1/F.
    s = dplyr::recode(as.character(s), "TRUE" = "-1", "FALSE" = "1")
  ) |> 
  dplyr::filter(cumulative) |>                # Drop everything afterwards
  dplyr::ungroup() |> 
  dplyr::arrange(ID, Rounds, row_id, index) |>  # Reverse again
  dplyr::group_by(row_id, ID, Rounds) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(
    solution_resp = paste(s, collapse = ", "),  # Smush back in a row
    element_count = dplyr::n(),                 # Quick count for inspection
  ) |> 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   row_id    ID Rounds solution_resp             element_count
    <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                             <int>
 1      1     2      0 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1                 7
 2      2     2      1 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1                   6
 3      3     2      2 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1             8
 4      4     2      3 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1                 7
 5      5     5      0 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1                   6
 6      6     5      1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1             8
 7      7     5      2 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1                 7
 8      8     5      3 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1                   6
 9      9     9      0 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1             8
10     10     9      1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1                 7
11     11     9      2 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1                   6
12     12     9      3 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1             8
```

(I'm using the initial `dt <- data.frame(ID,Rounds,solution,solution_resp)` definition of `dt`).

Answer (score 1):

Using the original `dt <- data.frame(ID,Rounds,solution,solution_resp)` Do the following:

```
dt %>%
      mutate(across(contains('solution'),
            ~str_split(str_remove_all(.x,'\\[|\\]|(, ?1)\\1*\\]+$'), ',')))
  ID Rounds                    solution             solution_resp
1   2      0  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
2   2      1 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
3   2      2 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
4   2      3  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
5   5      0 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
6   5      1 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
7   5      2  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
8   5      3 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
9   9      0 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
10  9      1  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
11  9      2 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
12  9      3 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
```

in Base R:

```
dt[3:4] <- gsub('\\[|\\]|(, ?1)\\1*\\]+$', '', as.matrix(dt[3:4]))
dt[3:4]<-lapply(dt[3:4], strsplit, ',')
dt
   ID Rounds                    solution             solution_resp
1   2      0  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
2   2      1 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
3   2      2 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
4   2      3  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
5   5      0 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
6   5      1 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
7   5      2  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
8   5      3 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
9   9      0 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
10  9      1  -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
11  9      2 -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1       1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1
12  9      3 -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1
```